# PHPUnit - AssertCount fails when having multiple insertion methods

Tags: php, database, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Hey I just started using PHPUnit. I'm trying to test the insertion of a model (called **Actor**) to the database. The creation of this model leads to create other models (Like **Subactor** and **Contact**). For this reason I have tested the creation of each model individually.

The problem is that when I attempt to run each test individually, everything works. However, when I try to run the whole class tests. The AssertCount method fails, since Each method adds a model therefore the count increments and the database doesn't refresh when running the whole class test.

[image]

I tried to initialize the count of each model at the beginning of each method but I thought that It wasn't the best solution.

Can anyone help ?

Thank you!

```
class ActorTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker;
    use RefreshDatabase;

    
    /** @test */
    public function an_actor_can_be_added()
    {
        $user = factory(Admin::class)->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('admin/actor',
        array_merge(factory(Actor::class)->make()->toArray(),
        ['contact'=>[factory(Contact::class)->make()->toArray()]]));
        
        $this->assertCount(1, Actor::all());
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_subactor_is_added_when_actor_created(){
        $user = factory(Admin::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('admin/actor',
        array_merge(factory(Actor::class)->make()->toArray(),
        ['contact'=>[factory(Contact::class)->make()->toArray()]]));

        $this->assertCount(1, Subactor::all());
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_contact_is_added_when_actor_created(){
        $user = factory(Admin::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('admin/actor',
        array_merge(factory(Actor::class)->make()->toArray(),
        ['contact'=>[factory(Contact::class)->make()->toArray()]]));

        $this->assertCount(1, Contact::all());
    }

    /** @test */
    public function an_actor_is_linked_to_subactor_when_created(){
        $user = factory(Admin::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('admin/actor',
        array_merge(factory(Actor::class)->make()->toArray(),
        ['contact'=>[factory(Contact::class)->make()->toArray()]]));

        $actor = Actor::first();
        $subactor = Subactor::first();
        
        $this->assertEquals($actor->id, $subactor->actor_id); 
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_subactor_is_linked_to_contact_when_created(){
        $user = factory(Admin::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('admin/actor',
        array_merge(factory(Actor::class)->make()->toArray(),
        ['contact'=>[factory(Contact::class)->make()->toArray()]]));

        $subactor = Subactor::first();
        $contact = Contact::first();
        
        $this->assertEquals($subactor->id, $contact->subactor_id); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're testing uses global states widely (via static methods), that's the reason your tests interfere each other. To avoid resetting the state in each method, you can either use a method with `@before` annotation or override `setUp()` nethod of your test-case class - and those code will be executed before each test method.

Comment: You mean that I should refresh the database in the setUp() method?

Comment: If refreshing database resets the state for your system under test and there's no cheaper ways to reset the state - then yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right solution but I did this.

```
protected function tearDown(): void
     {
         Actor::truncate();
         Subactor::truncate();
         Contact::truncate();
     }
```

Comment: You're right, but it's better to move that code to `setUp()` method (a simple mnemonic rule is "more set up than tear down"). The rationale is that `tearDown()` is generally not guaranteed to execute (due to the fatal error or stopping the tests manually) and it can make the next run failing, which is especially painful on CI pipelines. Thus the common practice is to clean the state in `setUp()`.